# Book about a few men stranded on an island where they can build anything out of nothing e.g. nitrocellulose powered guns

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for a book I read when I was young, which told the story of some gentlemen stranded on an island "Crusoe style". If I remember correctly, it was placed in the early XX or late XIX century.

The castaways were able to build quite advanced technology out of nothing, with the most memorable thing being nitrocellulose powered guns.

Comment: Are there any science fiction or fantasy elements? Otherwise, this seems a better match for the Literature SE.

Comment: You say you read it when you was young, when was that? Can you also remember anything that happened plotwise? Did they escape? Why did they need the guns? etc. Is there anything else you can edit in that you remember?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Building nitrocellulose powered guns out of nothing seems pretty SFF-nal to me but you're right that it _might_ not be.

Comment: Probably depends on how "out of nothing" it is. If they're conjuring guncotton, employing an alien artifact to fashion the guns, or using a heretofore unknown chemical process, that's SFF. If they're refining nitric acid and pouring it over wood fibers, much less so.

Comment: Was there a guy named Gilligan?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That sounds very much like Jules Verne's [*The Mysterious Island*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mysterious_Island) (published 1874).   They build guns, nitroglycerin and a whole 1860's high-tech civilization using just their own knowledge, and the resources of the island (which also happens to include a hidden Capt. Nemo of the *Nautilus* who gives them a bit of help from time to time). Nonetheless, they do most of it on their own.

Comment: Saying that there's a certain thing on the island is a spoiler. It's the reason behind several mysterious events throughout the book, and it's discovered only towards the end. Can I suggest to edit it out, or hide it under a spoiler tag? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, that was It! Thank you!